# Convert lambda_http Body object to string type?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. I have a lambda_http Request object and I would like to obtain the text of the Body as a string.

I'm reading the [docs on Body](https://docs.rs/lambda_http/0.1.1/lambda_http/enum.Body.html) but am too new to Rust to understand what I'm looking at. Possibly I need to use the `Text` attribute somehow?

Current code:

```
async fn process_request(request: Request) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, std::convert::Infallible> {
    let body = request.body();
    let my_string = body.to_string();
    if let Err(e) = write_to_dynamodb(&my_string).await {
        eprintln!("Error: {}", DisplayErrorContext(e));
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
let my_string = body.to_string();
|                          ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&lambda_http::Body` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I be reading the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Since [`Body` derefs to `&[u8]`](https://docs.rs/aws_lambda_events/0.7.3/src/aws_lambda_events/encodings.rs.html#253-260), use [`std::str::from_utf8()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) (you can call `to_owned()` if you want `String` and not `&str`):

```rust
let body = request.body();
let my_string = std::str::from_utf8(body).expect("non utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

in the docs you linked, it looks like the Body is an enum. If you want it as a string, you'd first have to check if the enum is Text like this:

```rust
    let body = request.body();
    if let lambda_http::Body::Text(my_string) = body {
        println!("{}", my_string);
        // do stuff here with my_string
    }
```

Comment: I want to get the text from the body and assign it to `my_string`.

Comment: in the if block my string will be a string, i'll edit the code for more clarity